# root ownership after mounting a drive with ext4 format

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4, chmod, chown

I have formatted with ext4 format by GParted:

(1) an USB flash drive and

(2) an external hard drive.

So far so good, but now they have root ownership and non edit permissions.
[image]

I can update the ownership and permission by `sudo chown/chmod`, but next time I will mount them, they will have again the root ownership.

How can I apply these changes permanently?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu /
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS /
Release: 18.04 /
Codename: bionic

Comment: Try this way: Create a directory in the file system (a subdirectory inside the mountpoint), and set its ownership and permissions with chown and chmod to get what you want. These settings should survive umount, shutdown or reboot and mount again.

Comment: @sudodus your approach works, thanks. Why doesn't it work applying the change from the root directory in the mountpoint? I can live with this extra directory, but I would like to get rid of it

Comment: How do you mount the ext4 partition on the drive? Automount (via fstab or udev) or do you mount it manually? It might be possible to modify the way to mount or maybe modify the ownership and permissions of the mountpoint (unless it is automatic)? But I suggested using a [sub]directory for a reason - It should work also when the drive is connected to some other computer.

Comment: It is automounted just after plugging it. The subdirectory solution sounds good